# Need to store Google Place Api Data and Manage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to create web services to manage and store google place api data on user and location level.

I need suggestion on database structure since I am using MongoDb, I have to create a model but I am not able to do that because I do not know what fields have to store in my database.

One example functionality Storing the searches a user make for specific location so that can be retrieved later or used for analytics.

Comment: I would start with the place id. Every Google Place have their own id so in Places Model it should be stored. Also, multiple users can search for the same location so mixed attributes in places with user _id and timings when they searched it.
You gotta remember that's the beauty of MongoDb its never too late to add or remove attributes to a model. Also regarding what other attributes you need to store it totally depends on your requirement.